# How to make a Query for seaching two different data string in two different columns?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, sql-in

Now I had made a Table say `PinDistance` in MySQL with Columns `PinCode1`, `PinCode2`, `Distance`.
And I have a record like this.
-------------------------------------
| PinCode1 | PinCode2 | Distance |
-------------------------------------
|  400001   |  400002   |        2       |
-------------------------------------
|  400004   |  400001   |        5       |
-------------------------------------

Now I want to pass two pincodes say '400001' and '400002'
and I want to Distance in response in a query such that query checks both columns and get the data.
Currently I am doing like the following 
`Select Distance from PinDistance where PinCode1 = '400001' and PinCode2 = '400002'` - IF I get data from this then I stop here else I pass another query interchanging pincode values simultaneously.

`Select Distance from PinDistance where PinCode1 = '400002' and PinCode2 = '400001'` 
 Is there any better way to do this???

Comment: Is it important that you know which part of the query found the Distance?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope, not at all. I just need the answer. An answer given for this question but your answer is also welcomed. Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT Distance 
FROM PinDistance 
WHERE ('400001', '400002') IN ((PinCode1, PinCode2), (PinCode2, PinCode1));
```

If there is a case that both combinations ('400001', '400002') and ('400002', '400001') may exist in the table and you want only 1 row as the result you can add `LIMIT 1` to the query.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/R-FZcq5A).

Comment: Oh, I use `IN` operator very often but I wan not aware that I can place values in where clause and column names in place of values. Thank You so much.